# How download pdf result without previewing and without changing page in nuxt project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jspdf, html2canvas

[image: in here i have 2 buttons]

In my main page, when user clicked download button, i send necessary parameters to store and i obtain necessary informations for my pdf page. In this page I want to download my pdf component but i dont wanna show it in my page . Just download by clicking download button . No routing any page.

```
  <ticket-print  v-if="pdfData" :pdfData="pdfData" ></ticket-print>
```

If i use pdf component in my main page, it appears in my project and I do not wanna show pdf result in here . Even if ı download like this, my pdf result faces with slips on the page.

```
  <ticket-print class="d-none"  v-if="pdfData" :pdfData="pdfData" ></ticket-print>
```

If i use like this in my main page , my pdf result return only one empty page .

I use jsPdf and html2canvas to convert it to pdf.

When I created main page , i already create necessary states in my store for pdf print . My aim is to download it directly in my main page without seeing preview of my pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any answers but i applied a trick and i dont know what kind suprise waits me at future. In here, i used my pdf component and with little trick i hide it

```
  <div style="height: 0;position:  fixed;left: 50%; top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);z-index: -1;overflow: hidden">
            <ticket-pdf v-if="pdfData" :pdfData="pdfData"/>
        </div>
```

Also left: 50%; top: 0;  transform: translateX(-50%) with thtese codes, i fix it to top and center so when i downloaded pdf i dont face with slips on my pages